Create symlink in powershell relative to the working directory
How can I make a symbolic link in Powershell relative to the working directory, rather than relative to the Path (without changing my working directory)
In GNU/linux command I can do it like this
ln -s -r ./change/99.md ./abuse/change/99.md

resulting in
.
├── abuse
│   └── change
│       └── 99.md -> ../../change/99.md
└── change
    └── 99.md

So this does NOT work in Powershell 7.1
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path ".\abuse\change\99.md" -Target ".\change\99.md"


What happens? Does -Path ".\abuse\change\99.md" -Target "$PWD\change\99.md" work?

Note that v7.1 of PowerShell (Core) 7 is no longer supported; as of this writing, the only supported version is v7.4 (which is also an LTS version; v7.5 is upcoming).


While PowerShell (Core) 7 - unlike Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1) - supports storing relative target paths as such in symlinks (symbolic links), you need to pass them explicitly to the New-Item cmdlet's -Target parameter.
By contrast (at least as of PowerShell 7.4.x), New-Item does not offer a parameter that is analogous to GNU ln's -r option, where the relative path to target is inferred from one given one on creation, relative to the location of the link itself.

Therefore, determine the desired relative path yourself, and pass it directly as the link target (it will be interpreted and stored as relative to the location of the link, not to the current directory):
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink .\abuse\change\99.md -Target ..\..\change\99.md


In PowerShell v7.4+, you can determine the relative path programmatically, using the Resolve-Path cmdlets with its -Relative and -RelativeBase parameters, assisted by Split-Path, though doing so is nontrivial:
$lnkPath = '.\abuse\change\99.md'
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink $lnkPath -Target (
  Resolve-Path -Relative -RelativeBasePath (Split-Path $lnkPath) (Resolve-Path .\change\99.md)
)

Note:

-RelativeBasePath must be a directory path, hence the use of Split-Path (the -Parent switch is implied). The -Relative switch is also needed, to ensure that the result is expressed as a relative path.

Since the (positionally implied) -Path argument (the last one above) would be interpreted as relative to the -RelativeBasePath argument if a relative path were given, it is first resolved to a full path via a nested Resolve-Path call.

General notes (not a problem with the specific paths at hand):

Resolve-Path and Convert-Path, unfortunately, only work with existing paths - see GitHub issue #2993 for a green-lit feature request meant to address this via a new switch, but  no one has stepped up to implement it yet.

Using positional parameter binding with the cmdlets in question binds to the -Path parameter (e.g., New-Item foo is the same as New-Item -Path foo), which interprets its arguments as wildcard expressions; since in PowerShell [ and ] are wildcard metacharacters too (not just * and ?), you may have to use the -LiteralPath parameter to ensure literal interpretation.

Unfortunately, Resolve-Path's -RelativeBasePath parameter invariably interprets its arguments as wildcard expressions, even though it arguably never should - see GitHub issue #20931




